# PrintThis override custom CSS when pressing button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printthis

I use PrintThis Jquery plugin.
I use Bootstrap as my framework.

When printing with PrintThis i´d like to lower my font size.
I've just made a Style change in the doc. like this:

```
<style>
body {
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
</style>
```

When the page first load. All text is 8px.
But when i press the PrintThis button, the page reloads/changes all text to Bootstrap default 14px.
Why is that?

**HTML for printButton**

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="print_btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" title="Print"></span></button>
```

**JS for printThis**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#print_btn').click(function () {
      $('#usr_name, #list_usr_time, #sum_worked_time,  #break_page').printThis();
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPPDATE**
I moved the style from the page, into a CSS file.
Then i loaded the css file into the page.
Also i added: loadCSS: "css/custom_printthis.css", to the custom Jquery.
The result is, page does not override css. The text is 8px, just as i want. BUT, when i press Print, the preview shows 14px text inside table tags... and 8px text outside. Maby i need to add "table.tex" in my css...

Comment: can you create a fiddle or bootply reproducing the issue?

Comment: @Ted i will try. I use php to populate the table wich i print. But i will try setting up one!

Comment: @Ted This is a fiddle. But the print btn wont work at all in the fiddle?! https://jsfiddle.net/kv5eeak7/

Comment: @Ted When i study the "Network" console in Chrome. I can see, when i press "print btn" the page reloads, and all script does to. But somehow, my "style" in that page isn't loading with it.. PrintThis must skip that custom style, added just before all html. Can it be because the "Style" isn't within some "Head" tags?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this i created a new class for all text printed by php.
Then i created a CSS file for that class, and overrited Bootstrap's original font-size.

```
<td class="table_text">Text</td>

.table_text{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```